# Не могу установить Nats

Tags: golang

Мне нужно установить пакеты Nats.
Проблема заключается в том, что когда я пишу команду

```
go install github.com/nats-io/nats.go@latest
```

То получаю ошибку:

```
package github.com/nats-io/nats.go is not a main package
```

Я так и не нашел , как можно исправить эту ошибку. Можете подсказать, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

добавьте слеш в конце пакета `nats.go/`

вот из официальной документации.
# Go client
go get github.com/nats-io/nats.go/

```
# Server
go get github.com/nats-io/nats-server

# Go client latest или точная сервия
go get github.com/nats-io/nats.go/@latest
go get github.com/nats-io/nats.go/@v1.23.0

# последняя версия NATS Server, добавьте /v2 в конец
go get github.com/nats-io/nats-server/v2

# NATS Server v1 установлен в противном случае
# go get github.com/nats-io/nats-server
```

Comment: Если добавить слэш, то будет ошибка:  ` go: github.com/nats-io/nats.go/@latest: argument must be a clean package path `

Comment: что конкретно вы исполнили? у меня все отработало коррекно https://pastebin.com/Kj9Rt70f . надо из директории go.mod вашей исполнять команды